# How to Find value in Text of list item by entering id or serial of item

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a list (it is much longer than this code, approx. 700-800 items)

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_serial"> </asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btn_find">Find </asp:Button>

<ul id="AllProducts" class="ui-droppable">
    <li class="ui-draggable" value="0">Sterling Silver Jesus Name Necklace( 101-01-071-02)</li>
    <li class="ui-draggable" value="101">14k 'Gold' 'Comfort Fit' Inside's Engraved Ring( 101-14-001-01)</li>
    <li class="ui-draggable" value="1000">Jewelry Polishing Cloths( 106-01-002-01)</li>
</ul>
```

When I enter the product serial number (displayed within the text of each `<li>` item) in a text field I would like to see the corresponding item selected in the list below, so that I do not need to look for it in the whole list.

e.g.:

- enter `(106-01-002-01)`
- see the entry `Jewelry Polishing Cloths` highlighted

So the goal is something similar to auto-complete, but to highlight an entry when there is a match to my search.

Comment: I don't see any connection to Java in this question therefore I will remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this

```
$("#searchBtn").on("click", function(event){
    $("#AllProducts li:contains('" + $("#searchText").val() + "')").css("background", "#ccc");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vkuD9/1/

Comment: The OP says "I don't want to look through the whole list". I'm pretty sure that's what *contains* will do (and there's no jQuery tag on the question).

Comment: Johnny Ha This is 99% exactly want i need , it real selecting the right item,but do you know how can i force the scroll-er go to right place where is the selected item,because item is selected  by color but i still need to scroll down to find it

Comment: Sorry didn't see that this hasn't jQuery tag.

Comment: Yes i did using drag and grop i need to find this product i the list by find button  and the drag it to cart

Comment: If u put a id on each li element, u can use $(document).scrollTop( $("#id").offset().top );

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index like:

```
var index = {'101-01-071-02':0,'101-14-001-01':1,'106-01-002-01':2};
```

Then you can find the LI something like:

```
var value = '106-01-002-01';
var lis = document.getElementById('AllProducts').getElementsByTagName('li');

if (value in index) {
  var theOne = lis[index[value]];
}
```

Note that *getElementsByTagName* returns a live NodeList, so you can get the collection once then modify the list of LIs in the DOM all you like, the collection will always reflect the LIs that are the descendants of "AllProducts".

You could also use an array with *indexOf*.

#### Edit

Here's a fiddle that does the job: http://jsfiddle.net/jPKtz/. It builds the index, selects the product if the product serial number is correct, and clears previous entries.

Comment: I don't really wont to build another array that contains 800-1000 items i just want to enter the serial number and to find/select it in the list some think like this i need to run over all li and ask if li Text contains (101-14-001-01) and if true select it  but cat find the way to do it

Comment: I thought you didn't want to loop over all the elements for performance reasons. Any approach you take must do that because there is no built-in index of random text in the document, hence the suggestion to build an index. You only need to build it once. Otherwise, put the product serial in the ID or class or whatever attribute so you can use DOM methods to get the LI.